# Prevent syncdb from updating database in Django?

Tags: database, django

I'd like to respect the database as a "read-only" and never write to it.  Is there a way to easily prevent syncdb from even bothering to check to update the database?

With Django 1.2 and the ability to have multiple databases, it'd like to be able to query a database for information.  I'd never need to actually write to that database.

However, I'd be scared if syncdb ran and attempted to update that database (because I may not have a technically read-only account to that database).  Mainly, I'd just like to use/abuse the Django ORM as a way to query that database.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I need to be able to sync one of the databases in settings.py, just not this specific one.

Comment: but syncdb is for synchronisation of your models and the database... for me it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heh, I guess I'll answer my own question (RTFM!)...

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example

```
def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
     ...
```

That's a definite start...

Comment: It's now called `allow_migrate`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `syncdb`, don't run it, simple as that. Updating the database is what it does, so if you don't need that, you shouldn't run it - it doesn't do anything else.

However if you're actually asking how to prevent syncdb from running at all, one possibility would be to define a 'dummy' syncdb command inside one of your apps. Follow the [custom management command instructions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) but just put `pass` inside the command's `handle` method. Django will always find your version of the command first, making it a no-op.

Comment: When automating deployment (using `ansible` or `puppet` or `heroku`) it's useful to selectively prevent syncdb from running on some of your read-only databases. Warning: A NOOP `management.command.syncdb` in any of your apps prevents `syncdb` from running on **any** of your apps in that project. And I don't think you can undo that behavior by linking to the core.management.command.syncdb for those apps you want to sync.

Answer (score 0):

This issue came up for me when working with read-only mirrors of Microsof SQL Server databases (uhhg). Since you can't selectively run `syncdb` on a single app or database. But you *have* to run `syncdb` when you first create a new Django project or install an new app that requires it (like `south`). What I did was to put my read-only database in its own Django app and then add an empty South migration to that app. That way `syncdb` thinks south is handling db setup for those apps, and `south` doesn't do anything to them!

```
manage.py schemamigration ap_with_read_only_database --empty initial_empty_migration_that_does_nothing
```

That leaves you free to manage the schema of that db outside of django.